# Is it possible to stream a video from FMLE directly to an media player without a mediation of FMS?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, flash-media-server, fmle

I want to know if it is possible to stream a video from FMLE (Flash Media Live Encoder) directly to an media player without a mediation of FMS (Flash Media Server) since I don't want to restream it to many users?

Here is schematics of what I want (I hope it better explains my question): http://s12.postimg.org/x4glz1l59/My_Scheme.png

If it is possible then what media player(s) can do that?

Also if you know more tool like FMLE (Flash Media Live Encoder) or FFmpeg which can be controlled over command line please let me know!

P.S.
Thank you for your answers and suggestions also I hope that you like my drawing skills... :D

Answer (score 0):

Do you think if we can do that, Adobe will give us [FMLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Flash_Media_Live_Encoder) for free ? Of course **NO**, you can not do that because FMLE, as its name indicate and as it's defined by [Adobe](http://www.adobe.com/products/flash-media-encoder.html), it's just a live encoder :

> Adobe® Flash® Media Live Encoder 3.2 live audio and video capture software is a media encoder that streams audio and video in real time to Adobe Media Server software or Flash Video Streaming Service (FVSS).

You can also use it to save your stream as FLV or F4V file locally and then use it in local or with a web server to play it with flash video player.

In addition, if you mean by "stream a video from FMLE", stream a video file as an input instead of video and audio devices, that to my knowledge is impossible without using a third-party software (as virtual video device).

Of course, everything I said is valid until the latest version which is FMLE 3. For more details about FMLE, you can take a look on [how to use ADOBE FLASH MEDIA LIVE ENCODER 3](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashMediaLiveEncoder/3.0/Using/flashmedialiveencoder_3_help.pdf) and its [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Flash_Media_Live_Encoder).

Hope that can help you.